# Wpf Desktop Api call duration more longer than actual api response time about 8-10 seconds

Tags: c#, wpf, api, request, duration

Here is case: 
I have wpf application on about 80 clients and they communicate single .net framework api for data process. I have stopwatch tracker some places for tracking durations on Wpf and api apps. Code samples :

My api attribute :

```
public class DurationControlLoggerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var controller = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        var action = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

        actionContext.ActionArguments.Add("_stopwatch_", Stopwatch.StartNew());
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiLogger"].ToLower().Trim() != "true")
            return;

        var controller = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        var action = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

        var stopWatch = (Stopwatch)actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionArguments["_stopwatch_"];

        stopWatch.Stop();

        var scope = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope();
        var commonService = (ICommonService)scope.GetService(typeof(ICommonService));
        commonService.InsertLog(new Model.Common.LogModel
        {
            InsertDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
            LogLevel = "API",
            MachineName = "API",
            Message = $"Controller : {controller} - Action : {action} - TotalSeconds : {stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}",
            StackTrace = string.Empty
        });
    }
}
```

Action sample :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [DurationControlLogger]
    public bool InsertProduct(ProductModel model)
    {
        return _mainService.TracingService.InsertProduct(model);
    }
```

This action process duration is about 0,03 seconds. On the other hand, wpf api call duration is about 10 seconds. Wpf code blocks are down below:

```
            var Stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var isSuccess = DataHelper.InsertProduct(Product);
            Stopwatch.Stop();
            if (Stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds > 2)
                DataHelper.InsertTraceLog($"ProducrtBusiness - InsertProduct TotalSecond : {Stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}");
```

**DataHelper.InsertProduct** method does basic http post request. Code is here :

```
public static class HttpClientHelper
{
    public static T Post<T>(object model, string url)
    {
        var resultStatus = false;
        T resultData = default(T);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
                resultStatus = response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
                resultData = result;
            }
        }
        return resultStatus ? resultData : default(T);
    }
    .....
```

Does anyone has any idea about that situation?

**EDIT**

I add one last log code. Here is code: 
`
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

```
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;

            stopwatch.Stop();
            if (stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds > 2)
            {
                AppendToFile($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} - {model.ToString()} - {stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} - Content: {jsonData}");
            }
```

`

This log duration still sometimes is 8-10 sec.

Comment: I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and look at following on both methods 1) Is the data compressed/encoded 2) Do you see http 1.0 (stream mode) or 1.1 chunk mode.  The version will be in the header 3) Check the time between the request and the response to determine if the delay is on the client or server.

Comment: Thank you for advice @jdwend. I install wireshark on client machine for tracking network traffic (p.s. : fiddler didnt work because of policy). I have checked all data traffic and every request duration has under 1 sec. But still i have 8-10 sec logs.. the issue in client machine.

Comment: How large is the log file.  It seems the appending of the log file is taking very long.  How much space is left on the drive?   What type of drive are you using (Solid State or Hard Drive)?  In the sniffer are you seeing in the response a status of 200 OK?  Is the delay occurring due to the AppendToFile or the jason deserialization?

Comment: @jdweng, im seeing status 200 OK in sniffer about every request. I found a solution. I will post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is likely (from what Ive seen) that you are running this code on the main message pump, (UI thread). During this method call you are performing an asynchronous call (PostAsync) and calling the 'Result' - making it run synchronously. However, while your UI thread was waiting, some other messages (UI updates?) where queued on the message pump, and were processed before your call to end the stopwatch (higher DispatcherPriority?) - delaying the timer end.
This is pure speculation, but I would recommend that you use some async/await in your asynchronous code, and try and perform these data access tasks on a separate thread

Comment: You are right; i think i have some thread issues. Because of this, i changed HttpClientHelper post method to async method. It works. The Code in my answer down below.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my HttpClientHelper class post method to this :

```
public static async Task<T> PostAsync<T>(object model, string url)
    {
        var resultStatus = false;
        T resultData = default(T);

        using (var client = new HttpClient(
                new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    UseProxy = false
                }
            ))
        {

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

            stopwatch.Stop();
            if (stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds > 2)
            {
                AppendToFile($"{DateTime.Now.ToString()} - {model.ToString()} - {stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} - Content: {jsonData}");
            }

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
                resultStatus = response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
                resultData = result;
            }
        }
        return resultStatus ? resultData : default(T);
    }
```

**client.PostAsync()** method has to **run async** for my issue. I think that related some thread managment issues. But this code works for me now.

Comment: Run Async should not have anything to do with solving issue.   It could be you were timing out, or the server was down and it finally came up so your code is working.